# how to put image in array string to view the picture in runtime

Tags: java, arrays, image, netbeans, imageview

Hot to put images on array of question (String ques[]) to view the picture in runtime??

because in the next question it will serve as picture not text like

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC2BT.png) this picture is an example of the question that will turn to picture

this code is a quiz game for lto examination
please bare with my codes

sorry if i am noob in java

i am self learning

Thank you!!!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
class LtoQuiz implements ActionListener
{
JFrame fr;
JRadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3;
JButton b1,b2;
JLabel lb1,lb2;
ButtonGroup bg;
String ques[]={"1.The three colors of the traffic lights are:",
    "2.Yellow triangular signs provide what kind of information"
,""};                                                           //how to put image on this array???

String op1[]={"red, green and yellow"
        ,"warning"
        ,"regulatory signs"};

String op2[]={"red, green and blue"
        ,"hospital across"
        ,"information signs"};

String op3[]={"yellow, green and blue"
        ,"speed limit"
        ,"danger warning signs"};

String ans[]={"red, green and yellow"
        ,"warning"
        ,"information signs"};

int cn;
LtoQuiz()
{
fr=new JFrame();
fr.setLayout(null);
fr.setSize(600,600);
Container c=fr.getContentPane();
c.setBackground(Color.cyan);

lb1=new JLabel(ques[0]);
lb1.setBounds(50,50,800,30);
fr.add(lb1);
lb1.setFont(new Font("chiller",Font.BOLD,25));

rb1=new JRadioButton(op1[0]);
rb1.setBounds(100,150,400,30);
fr.add(rb1);

rb2=new JRadioButton(op2[0]);
rb2.setBounds(100,200,400,30);
fr.add(rb2);
rb3=new JRadioButton(op3[0]);
rb3.setBounds(100,250,400,30);
fr.add(rb3);
bg =new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(rb1);
bg.add(rb2);
bg.add(rb3);
rb1.addActionListener(this);
rb2.addActionListener(this);
rb3.addActionListener(this);

b1=new JButton("Sumbit");
b1.setBounds(100,400,100,30);
fr.add(b1);

b2=new JButton("Next");
b2.setBounds(250,400,100,30);
fr.add(b2);
b1.addActionListener(this);
b2.addActionListener(this);
fr.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String s[])
{
new LtoQuiz();

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
if(e.getSource()==b1)
{

String en="";
if(rb1.isSelected())
en=rb1.getText();
if(rb2.isSelected())
en=rb2.getText();
if(rb3.isSelected())
en=rb3.getText();
if(en.equals(ans[cn]))
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Right Answer");
else
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Answer");
}
if (e.getSource()==b2)
{
cn++;
lb1.setText(ques[cn]);
rb1.setText(op1[cn]);
rb2.setText(op2[cn]);
rb3.setText(op3[cn]);
}
}
}
```